# Meaning of \[\e]0; in PS1 in .bashrc

Tags: bash, prompt, escape-characters

In `.bashrc`

```
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac
```

I understand `${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w`, but not `\[\e]0;`. What does it make?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `\e]0;` is an escape sequence; `\e` is replaced with ASCII 27 (ESC), so the terminal receives the 4 characters  `ESC ] 0 ;` tells xterm to set icon and title bar, that ends in BEL (`\a`).

So the sequence `\e]0;STUFFGOESHERE\a` will set the title of the terminal to STUFFGOESHERE.   In your example it'll set the title to user/host/path.

FWIW, xterm escape sequences are documented at: https://www.x.org/docs/xterm/ctlseqs.pdf

Comment: TLDR; That sequence sets the *title bar* to the working directory.

Answer (score 6):

The characters `\e]0;` in the line

```
PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
```

are interpreted by the shell (equating `\e` to `\033` the ASCII ESC *escape* character), ***beginning*** an escape sequence.  The sequence ***ends*** on `\a` (likewise interpreted by the shell \007` ASCII BEL *bell*).

The `0` is a parameter (for what's known as an *operating system command*), which tells the terminal to change both icon and window titles.

Technically it ought to be `\e\\` (ECMA-48), however that's not how it started.  When the feature was first introduced in 1986, `xterm` terminated the title on the first non-printing character.
The `\a` has been recognized as a string terminator by xterm since X11R4 in 1989 (when separate parameters `1` and `2` were added to distinguish the icon and window titles).

`rxvt` picked this up a couple of years later, and a few years later xterm was modified to *also* accept a standard string terminator.  No particular point was made in the changelog, but it appeared in `ctlseqs.ms` first in August 1996. Generally when other terminals have implemented the feature they accept `\a` only.

Without the ending, the isolated escape character could be treated as an error in a terminal-specific manner (including ignoring the text altogether).

Further reading:

- [XTerm Control Sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html)
- [`ctlseqs.ms` (August 1996)](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/xterm-snapshots/commit/5b1d5388811009e7b639017495421cdba6b1edd5#diff-6ecd9e2b29c15be27482e02f8cae8270R749).
- [ECMA-48: Control Functions for Coded Character Sets](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-048.htm)

Edit: fixed typo