# How to prepend title in Gnome Terminal?

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal

See below example. I want to prepend the piece `orschiro@x230` with the currently running command.

Right now, the command is showing after the piece.

I want to show it at the beginning because it helps me find the right window more easily among list of open windows because I can only see the first letters but not the end.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Has your research led you to tweaking some `.bashrc` statements?

Comment: Yes but that only affected the prompt inside the terminal itself. Wasn't able to manipulate the terminal window title itself.

Comment: Does https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/306716 help you?